# Почему программисты пренебрегают iframe'ами?

Tags: html, iframe

Добрый день, друзья. Очень часто, на форумах, я вижу информацию о том, что **iframe** - это плохо, это "моветон" веб-разработчика. Читал несколько статей, но так и не смог окончательно разобраться, почему **iframe** - это плохо.

**Q:** Есть какие-то соображения, почему не стоит использовать iframe, чем это чревато, или наоборот, почему его можно использовать?

Comment: в некоторых  случаях (визуальный редактор, передача файла js без file api) без iframe никуда.

Comment: Ок, это отнесем к плюсам iframe. Спасибо )

Comment: реклама в iframe - это очень хорошо. Одна строка в свой css и получаешь нормальные страници без ужаса.

Comment: Наверно потому что не хватило мозгов понять, как с этим тегом правильно работать. Не вижу ничего плохого.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081315/why-developers-hate-iframes

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96748/are-iframes-a-terrible-idea

http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34793/using-iframes-is-still-considered-bad

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С iframe не чувствуешь свободу действий. Особенно с js. Написав js код в родителе, вы не можете управлять элементами и данными в дочерних фреймах. Это политика безопасности.

Comment: Да ладно? А у меня получилось и контнентом управлять:

 var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
 var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument;

И получить функцию iframe'a:

 var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
 var innerDoc = iframe.contentWindow;
 
 innerDoc.function();

Политика безопасности говорит о том, что управление контентом в ifame недоступно только для различных доменов родителя и iframe'a.